# Converting single object inside list mapsturct

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

How can I do Response Mapping MapStruct for the below scenario

My model is below;

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class TaskList {

   private Long taskStatus;
}
```

My Response is below;

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class TaskResponse {

 private Long taskStatus;
}
```

I am wrapping Response pojo to Response List below;

```
public class AllTaskListResponse {
  
   private List<TaskResponse> taskResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

My enumTask below;

```
public enum TaskStatusEnum {
  
  Sth(1);
  Sth(2);

private final long value;

TaskStatusEnum(long value) {

  this.value = value;
}

 public static TaskStatusEnum get(long value) {

 for (TaskStatusEnum status : TaskStatusEnum.values()) {
     
   if(status.value == value) {

    return status;
  
   }
 }

  return null;
 }
}
```

My TaskList Mapper below;

```
 @Named("taskStatusToString")
public static TaskStatusEnum taskStatusToString(long taskStatus) {
   
   return TasStatusEnum.get(taskStatus);
}

 @Mapping(source = "taskStatus", target = "taskStatus", qualifiedByName = "taskStatusToString")
 public abstract List<TaskResponse> toAllTaskListResponse(List<TaskList> taskList);
```

so When I try to run I got "Unmapped target property result" message I received

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because the method provided for mapping `taskStatus` field has a return type of `TaskStatusEnum`, however, `taskStatus` field is `Long` in both source and target.

Either, convert the target field type to enum like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class TaskResponse {
    private TaskStatusEnum taskStatus;
}
```

Or, remove the mapping for `taskStatus` field:

```
public abstract List<TaskResponse> toAllTaskListResponse(List<TaskList> taskList);
```

Also, another method for converting single `TaskList` to `TaskResponse` would be required for the list converting methods to work. The mapping for `taskStatus` should be applied there, if required. Something like this:

```
@Mapping(source= "taskStatus", target = "taskStatus", qualifiedByName= "taskStatusToString")
public abstract TaskResponse toTaskResponse(TaskList taskList);

public abstract List<TaskResponse> toAllTaskListResponse(List<TaskList> taskList);

@Named("taskStatusToString")
public static TaskStatusEnum taskStatusToString(long taskStatus) {
   return TasStatusEnum.get(taskStatus);
}
```

Mapstruct, will first implement the mapping between `TaskList` to `TaskResponse` and then in turn `List<TaskList>` to `List<TaskResponse>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the thing is I need to get Data inside of List. If ıts not in the list it works

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add one method. Mapstruct will need a method to convert `TaskList` to `TaskResponse` also, and the mapping should go to that method. Also, please note `taskStatusToString` returns `TaskStatusEnum` and `TaskResponse` expects a long.

Comment: hello I think is if ı make a body for my list I think is it will work but ı have no idea how to do  @Mapping(source= "taskStatus", target = "taskStatus", qualifiedByName
= ""taskStatusToString") public abstract TaskResponse toTaskResponse(TaskList taskList);             public abstract List<TaskResponse> toAllTaskListResponse(List<TaskList>taskList)

Comment: @john, it is same as the code you shared just added one more abstract method for converting `TaskList` to `TaskResponse` `public abstract List<TaskResponse> toAllTaskListResponse(List<TaskList> taskList);`. So, you just have to put this additional method in your class you won't need the implementation for list.